# How to use cosine transform to quickly solve $f(A)x=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, fast-fourier-transform

How to fast sovle a matrix linear system $f(A)x= b$, where $A$ is a tridiagonal matrix as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\\
  c & d & c & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\\
  0 & c & d & c & ... & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\\
  0 & 0 & c & d & ... & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\\
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &  \cdots & \cdots &\cdots& \cdots &\cdots&\cdots\\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...  & d & c & 0 & 0 \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...  & c & d & c & 0 \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...  & 0 & c & d & c  \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...  & 0 & 0 & b & a  \\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and f(x) is a polynomial function, for example $f(A) = 1 + A + A^2 + A^3$.

When the matrix $A$ is very large (1 million $\times $1 milion) (of course it is stored as a sparse matrix), the calculation cost is very high. For example, I encountered the problem of insufficient memory (64G) when solving the above equation.

It seems that using diagonalization is a good idea, but it is still difficult to calculate the diagonalization of such a large matrix.

There are some answers gave me a suggestion that I can use fast cosine transform to solve the equation. I want to know how this should be done. I would be very grateful if you can provide the corresponding literature or python code.